# Kotlin, HTML-encoding without Android?

Tags: kotlin

I am using Android Studio, but for quick testing, I am executing a Kotlin function on my PC without Android. I want to HTML-encode some string, and searching Google showed only `String.htmlEncode()`, but that seems to be an extension method that use Android. Running `"<b>".htmlEncode()` on PC results in

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: android/text/TextUtils

Is there a way to encode without Android? Or is there any way to import and use that Android `TextUtils` class on PC?

[image]

Comment: See https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html